# bridging mqtt brokers hivemq and mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, bridge, mosquitto, hivemq

I'm trying to bridge two MQTT brokers on the same system, `HiveMQ` and `Mosquitto`. `HiveMQ` is working on port `1884` and `Mosquitto` is running on `1883`. However when I use the `mosquitto_pub` command to publish to the `mosquitto` broker at port `1883`, it does not show up on port `1884` (Using `MQTT.fx` as a client subscribing to all topics on port `1884`)

This is while I only configured the `mosquitto` broker with a bridge. 
When I configured `HiveMQ` as well, it only shows an `unable to connect to Bridge1, disconnected` message on the `HiveMQ` command window. I've included the configurations below. Someone please help.

In the `mosquitto.config` file I have done the following under `bridges`.

```
    connection hivemq
    address 127.0.0.1:1884 
    start_type automatic
    clientid clientno1
    notifications true
```

Meanwhile, I also editted the `HiveMQ bridges.xml` file to read

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bridges xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.hivemq.com/bridges/bridge.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<bridge>
    <connectionName>Bridge1</connectionName>
    <addresses>
        <address>
            <host>localhost</host>
            <port>1883</port>
        </address>
    </addresses>
    <clientId>bridgeClient</clientId>
    <topicPatterns>
        <topicPattern>
            <topic>#</topic>
            <qos>1</qos>
            <direction>both</direction>
            <localPrefix>local/</localPrefix>
            <remotePrefix>remote/</remotePrefix>
        </topicPattern>
    </topicPatterns>
    <cleanSession>true</cleanSession>
    <idleTimeout>10</idleTimeout>
    <notificationsEnabled>true</notificationsEnabled>
    <tryPrivate>true</tryPrivate>

</bridge>
```

[image: The image below is when I tried the same process on another system. Here, the brokers are bridged. Comparing this to what I was doing earlier, the only difference is that on my original system there is no statement saying opening ipv4 listen socket on 1883. Is this the problem?]

The image shown is when I tried the same process on another system. Here, the brokers are bridged. Comparing this to what I was doing earlier, the only difference is that on my original system there is no statement saying opening ipv4 listen socket on 1883. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bridging should only be set on the publisher/client side (mosquitto in your case), leaving default settings on Hivemq (server) should be fine

Try make changes to your mosquitto.conf

```
connection bridge-mosquitto-to-hivemq
address 127.0.0.1:1884 
topic room1/# both 2 sensor/ myhouse/
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
notifications true
cleansession true
try_private true
```

After restart your brokers, at mosquitto broker, try publish an example message below

```
mosquitto_pub -t sensor/room1/temperature -m '26.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to have the bridge configured in one of the brokers, having bridges configured for both will lead to problems, most likely message loops

For your mosquitto config you need to add a *topic* line to your mosquitto bridge so it knows what topics to send (and receive) to the hive broker

The full details about the topic directive can be found in the mosquitto.conf man page (http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) but the basics are:

> topic pattern [[[ out | in | both ] qos-level] local-prefix remote-prefix]

To mirror all topics in both directions

```
topic # both
```

Comment: I only configured the bridge on `mosquitto` and also added in the topic line in the config file now. Still not bridging.

Comment: Does the mosquitto output show anything about the bridge?

Comment: Nothing at all. I can't tell whether it has even configured or not. Both are working perfectly separate, but `mosquitto` doesn't display anything about the bridge. I'm a bit perplexed.

Comment: When I try to configure the bridge via `HiveMQ` instead of `mosquitto` it says `trying to connect to bridge 'mosquitto' with target localhost:1883`

Followed by `Connected to bridge 'mosquitto' with target localhost:1883`

Then immediately changes to `bridge mosquitto got disconnected. restarting bridge in 30 seconds`

Comment: If mosquitto doesn't say anything about the bridge, try starting it as `mosquitto -v` to enable all logging.

Comment: @ralight when I do that, it says `using default config. opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883. Error:Unknown error` Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: Sorry of course you also need to tell mosquitto which config file to load: `mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf`

Comment: @ralight Now it displays `config loaded from mosquitto.conf. opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883. Error:Unknown error`

Can't quite pinpoint this error, it's too generic.

Comment: This isn't the place for an extended discussion. The ipv6 error is a red herring unless you are using ipv6.